# ASP.NET Session Management issue, When using the same url in multiple tab

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-variables, session-cookies, session-state

I have an ASP.NET application and generated a Menu using unordered list. On selecting the menu, I will maintain the selected menu using Session values.

Session Value issue in the below scenario:

1. Selected "A" menu in tab 1
2. Open new tab(tab 2) with same url and selected "B" menu
3. Go back to tab 1 and refresh the page
4. Go back to tab 2 and access the page without refresh. The session value of tab 1 persist.

Need your help to solve

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are different ways to do this, first let us know what have you tried?

Comment: This is not something that should be stored in server-side session state as it is not a business-logic concern, but a presentation-concern - you'll also run into issues with multiple windows in the same session - which is exactly what this problem is.

Comment: While selecting the menu, i will assign the value in session variable